# gnuplot, postscript: no coloring via linestyle

Tags: gnuplot, postscript

In the below code, the appearance of the curve plotted takes into account `linetype` and `linewidth` but it completely ignores `linecolor`.

```
set style line 1 linetype 1 linewidth 10 linecolor rgb "blue" 
plot \
myfile using 1:2 with lines linestyle 1
```

I have tried to change the order of these items, as well as different ways of specifying color, eg. "#0000FF" instead of "blue".

How can I change this to have the curve take on the color specified via `linestyle 1`?

This is gnuplot 5.4 on Mac OS / Big Sur, tried with "Terminal" and "iterm2".

---

**IMPORTANT UPDATE**

I'm using `set term postscript eps`. When i change this to `set term pngcairo` everything is ok.

So my updated question is: How to make this work also with `set term postscript eps`?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. What is your gnuplot version? What is your terminal? What is the color you get? What do you get when you do `test`?

Comment: thx. the output color is black, i get the same result with two different terminals: mac os default "Terminal" and on "iterm2". gnuplot is 5.4. sorry for my ignorance, tried to google test for gnuplot but could not get clear on how to do "that".

Comment: sorry, for not being clear. If you work with the gnuplot command line, simply type `test`.

Comment: thx, sorry for being thick. this produces a diagram with colored lines as expected it would seem.

Comment: There is the 'show' command to see what you have set in the 'set' command. By typing `show style line 1` after `set style line 1 …`, you can check if your settings are correctly reflected.

Comment: thx, this gives: linestyle 1,  linecolor rgb "blue"  linewidth 10.000 dashtype solid pointtype 1 pointsize default. hmm...?

Comment: What do you get when you type in the gnuplot console: `show term`?

Comment: "terminal type is qt 0 font "Sans,9"

Comment: @youwouldbesurprised Well, apparently qt termina is your default, but I meant the properties of the postscript terminal. What do you get if you type first `set term postscript eps` and then `show terminal`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the default setting for the postscript terminal is `monochrome` and you have to explicitely set `color`. I remember having seen similar questions in the past. I don't know why default is `monochrome`, maybe historical reasons? So, it seems to be a recurring "pitfall", since users nowadays think everything is in color per default ;-).

```
set term postscript eps color
```

That's what I get (on a "fresh" console) if I type `set term postscript eps`. Apparently, text is in color per default (i.e. labels and arrows), but the rest seems to be `monochrome`.

```
Options are 'eps enhanced defaultplex \
   leveldefault monochrome colortext \
   dashlength 1.0 linewidth 1.0 pointscale 1.0 butt noclip \
   nobackground \
   palfuncparam 2000,0.003 \
   "Helvetica" 14  fontscale 1.0 '
```

Comment: if it wasnt for users like you and stackoverflow, i cant imagine how long it would have taken me to find an answer to such a marginal question. thx a million!

Comment: thanks :-) Well, I'm just a user who acquired some knowledge on gnuplot. I admire and I'm grateful to those people who have been developing and keep developing gnuplot

Answer (score 0):

`set term epslatex`

...and it works! (since i wanted "eps", and got "eps").

Incidentially (although it produces "png" instead of "eps") `set term pngcairo` and possible many more "term"s also work.

Strange thing is that I didn't get any warning when plotting with `set term postscript eps` that gnuplot was not able to apply the linestyle coloring with that terminal mode.

Comment: Have you tried `set term postscript eps color`? I guess for some reason the default is `monochrome`.

Comment: thx, that worked! however, i was able to print other stuff (arrows and labels) in color with just ```set term postscript eps```; only the coloring of lines had no effect. very strange. thx a lot for your help. consider posting it as an answer and i will mark it as such.