# I want to plot the histogram using gnuplot. And it doesn't work

Tags: gnuplot, histogram

```
set term postscript eps
set output "result.eps"

set style data histogram
set style histogram rowstacked
set style fill solid 0.5
set boxwidth 1 relative

set xrange [0:31]
set xtics 1
set yrange [0:15]
set ytics 1

set title 'Studying time in May'
datafile = '../data/hour_formatting/May_formatted.txt'
data_under = '../data/under_ave/May_under.txt'
plot datafile using 2:xtic(1) with boxes title 'Studying time', data_under using 2:xtic(1) with boxes notitle fillcolor 'red''
```

In data_under, there is the data that 0 value only for above average value.

But the graph all colored with gray color.

[image]

I want to color only for the value below the average value. What is the problem, and how can I solve it?

I don't know what is the problem, so I cannot tried anything.

Comment: Have you tried `set term postscript eps color` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ethan already gave the hint about color in postscript terminal.
See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65215847/7295599).

It looks like you have used some software tool to split your data into above and below average.
Let me make a suggestion how you can simply do it with gnuplot from one single file (or datablock) containing your data, i.e. study time in hours per day of a certain month.

**Script:**

```
### show bar chart with differently colored bars below average
reset session

# create some random test data
set table $Data
    set samples 30
    plot '+' u ($0+1):(rand(0)*9 * int(rand(0)+0.8)) w table
unset table

stats $Data u 2 nooutput

myColor(v) = v < STATS_mean ? 0xff0000 : 0xcccccc
set style fill solid 1.0 border lt -1
set xrange[0:32]
set xtics out
set ylabel "studying time in hours"

plot $Data u 1:2:(myColor($2)):xtic(1) w boxes lc rgb var notitle, \
     STATS_mean w l dt 2 lc "black" ti "average"
### end of script
```

**Result:**

[image]